# push notification from DB2

Tags: push-notification, db2

i want to implement push notification from DB2.
I have two Database servers, **Server#1 is DB2** and **Server#2 is oracle** 11g. I have a situation where, whenever some data is inserted in DB2 I need to insert that data in Oracle as well.
I want to inquire whether Push notification from DB2 is the right option available or is there any other suitable way to look forward to.

Or more simply I just need to know whether there is any event available in DB2 when a row is inserted in it like SQL Dependency feature in SQL Server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

DB2 offers several options of getting data to another server. Here are some I can think of:

- SQL Trigger to react on insert/update/delete and to possibly send out a notification
- SQL Replication feature - this is based on triggers
- Q Replication would capture the changes and send them over
- Event Publishing would notify of change events, probably closed to what you are looking for

Start [here in the Q Replication and SQL Replication overview](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTRGZ_10.2.1/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.db.repl.intro.doc/topics/iiyrcintch100.html) to read about the features and differences.

Comment: Great...Dear i want to push data from DB2 to Oracle, SQL Dependency feature i used in the question for just reference only...it would be great if you can advise me in the context of DB2 and Oracle.

Comment: There are replication products for exactly that scenario. Please mark the question as answered.